# How can I build a mobile app that will publish images to ROS?

Tags: ros, cameras, software

I'd like to build a simple mobile app that allows the user to click a picture and then publish that picture via a topic to ROS.

How can I connect the app and ROS? What would my development environment look like?

And which version of ROS is recommended?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* SM5, but I'm afraid that questions asking for code are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given coding problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so please try to include what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask], [about] and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for advice on writing a good question.

Comment: There are [tutorials for creating a ROS publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29), but there aren't any details here about what you tried and what specifically you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not so trivial, however I would start with getting up and running following mobile app suite which provides some basic functionalities: https://github.com/ROS-Mobile/ROS-Mobile-Android

I assume that for Android App development you would need to use Android studio, and look into different nodes (there's also Camera node). With all nodes available you'll have to figure out how to modify a Camera node that enables selection of the image from your mobile phone, repacking that image into `sensor_msgs/Image` data and then sending (publishing) that image data on a certain topic.

I would reccomend ROS noetic because you have mobile app and you can start from that. However, ROS 2 is new and may also be a good option, however, you'll have to develop some stuff from scratch.

If you look into issues of the repo I've attached, you can find following [discussion](https://github.com/ROS-Mobile/ROS-Mobile-Android/issues/103), whereas maintainer says that there are some forks that have already implemented that what you want to do, so explore forks of that repo as well, and you may not need to program it yourself. Cheers :)

Comment: Appreciate your response! Is there any way to search forks by topic so I could find it?

Comment: You can find all forks [here](https://github.com/ROS-Mobile/ROS-Mobile-Android/forks?include=active&page=1&period=&sort_by=stargazer_counts). I don't know if you can search them by topic or any other keyword.